# Angular2 NPM installtion errors

Tags: angular

I am new to angular, I am trying to install npm which is required for angular 2. It git error in cli.

```
npm ERR! 404 'types' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-30-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/html/angularDemo
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! TypeError: Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:687:35)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:675:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:142:7)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-30-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/html/angularDemo
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! type non_object_property_load
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/router
npm ERR! TypeError: Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:687:35)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/cache.js:675:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:142:7)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/nodejs/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
```

Can anyone tell me what mistake I am doing while installation.

Installation commands

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git quickstart
cd quickstart
npm install
npm start
```

Comment: can you please post your `package.json` code ?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your `npm registry` is messed up.

`npm ERR! 404 'types' is not in the npm registry.`

execute `npm get registry` and see what registry is set. you can also see that in your `.npmrc` file in your class path.

you can point to public npm registry by `npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` or by editing the `.npmrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git quickstart
cd quickstart
npm install
npm start
```

When you clone the repo
Navigate into the folder `quickstart` created by the clone command using the terminal.
On the terminal, type `npm install`.
After the installation, type `npm start`, this runs the app.

Comment: i think he is also doing the same! what is different in your answer?